# pytorch tensor indices is confusing

Tags: numpy, pytorch

When I use `Pytorch` tensor indices, a strange result has occurred：

```py
import numpy as np  
import torch  
a = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], dtype=torch.long)  
b = np.zeros(shape=((32,500)))  
print(a[b])
```

The program is normal and the output is a `35*500` tensor, but when I change  the slices:

```py
c = np.zeros(shape=((31,500)))
print(a[c])
```

The program reported an error：

```
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

I don't know why. Please tell me why.
Thanks!

Comment: `a[b]` output shape should be `32x500` and not 35